# My xperia x10 is booting again and again 

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, boot

I just installed busybox and then my phone is rebooting again and again!!

What can I do to stop it?

I don't know how to boot it into recovery. I did it once (before I installed busybox) by clicking the back button when it's starting, but it's not working now.

I tried to do it from quick boot (while my phone stays on for a minute or less) but it doesn't work.

I have xperia x10 rooted to android 2.2 with cyanogenmod 6

Comment: Read the issues that arises with Cyanogenmod ROM. I faced the same issue. Finally reinstalled the Original ROM that comes up with my Xperia Mini Pro using SEUS.

Comment: where can i read them?how can i reinstall it ? in fact this is what i was meaning to do when i had this problem.any idea how can i fix this plz.thanks

Comment: Search for your ROM related information here :http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=617

Comment: I guess there is a updated version of Cyanogenmod ROM available. Download it and install it using xRecovery. If nothing works then use SEUS to format the phone and install the original ROM that comes with the Phone and try doing the same.

Comment: Yup man. SEUS is Sony Ericsson Update Service. You must have a PC with internet to do this. Download that software from http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/support/softwaredownloads/detailed/updateservice/xperiax10?cc=gb&lc=en. Install it and follow the steps.

Comment: After installation just follow the steps. But before even doing that back up all your data. You will loose everything with this installation.

Comment: I guess the following are the steps.Turn off the  phone, run SEUS until you are asked to connect the phone
Now connect the phone to your PC do not turn the phone on
Hold the back key and insert the USB do not let go of the back key until told to do so
SEUS will auto detect your phone at this point.

Comment: this is what ive done.then it says my phoe is up to date and it quit

Comment: Follow the steps here. Check the step no-6. It shows the install option even your phone has the updated software. http://www.guidingtech.com/mobiles/update-sony-ericsson-xperia-x10-to-android-eclair/

Comment: One thing - Your mobile had 2.1. You installed custom ROM to have the 2.2 version. And in the next quarter or later Sony Ericsson is going to release 2.3 version. I strongly recommend restore your phone with  the original ROM. If they releases any updates you will get informed in the notice bar.

Comment: Oh Man, thats the reason why you're not able to install the Original ROM. Sorry my answers won't applicable for your mobile. In that case you need to see the XDA forums regarding the Cyanogenmod ROM.

Comment: Guys, don't do this in comments.  Take it to the chatroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it :)

in case somebody is in the same situation, here is what i did:
i flashed my phone to its original rom using [flashtool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=920746)  (if u dont know how to use it go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=928343) )

thats it

thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try holding the "Back" key while turning the phone on.

It sounds as if the phone is in a boot loop.  Why did you need to install Busybox in the first place?  CyanogenMod (and most other custom ROMs) already has it included.  I would recommend re-flashing CM6 again.

Comment: i was/am trying to reinstall the rom cause its not working properly,followed a thread,that was the first step. holding the back button doesnt work!!